# Класс NSDate в Objective C

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Прочитал статьи на тему работа с классом NSDate. И стало немного не понятно: в статье две даты сравнивают методом isEqualToDate, но этот метод позволят лишь установить равны даты или нет, а если мне нужно конкретно узнать какая дата больше, либо меньше? Правильно ли будет использование `>, <, !=`  ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А как же сравнение дат в [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) !?

Comparing Dates

- isEqualToDate:
- earlierDate:
- laterDate:
- compare:

Comment: упс. В статье про это не было, а документацию apple я не читаю (по английски не оч понимаю). Спасибо.

Comment: По поводу статей на русском - есть очень много случаев, когда разного рода статьи на русском становятся злом. Главный источник - это всё таки Apple docs и их WWDC-сессии. Пускай это вдохновит вас на изучение языка - это не сложно, поверьте!

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо. Посмотрел в документацию apple, плохо что методы earlierDate,laterDate возвращают не bool а дату. Это очень неудобно.

Comment: Да, всё верно: посмотрите _compare:_.

Comment: Артур, если еще актуально, то вот полный перевод NSDate:  http://osxdev.ru/blog/objective-c/111.html